# How this macro works in Excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to Excel VBA and it's actually my first time using it.

I am not understanding this specific line in my macro, that is inserted in a closed loop:

`Sheets("LocalizedText").Range("E" & i2).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(col & i).Value`

If you need it here it is the full macro:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim i2 As Long
Dim col As String
col = "B"
i = 1
i2 = 1
Dim con As Long
con = 1
Do While con < 13425
    Sheets("LocalizedText").Range("E" & i2).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(col & i).Value
    i = i + 1
    i2 = i2 + 2
    con = con + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Can someone explain me how is this macro working?

Comment: Its copying lines 1 to 13424  from the Sheet Sheet1 column "B" to the Sheet LocalizedText column "E"

Comment: Thanks man, idk when it could be used but know i understand a little bit more of vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each row of column B from the sheet *Sheet1*, it will write the value into column E from sheets *LocalizedText* but leaving a blank row between 2 rows